# Sequelize findOrCreate including associates - "Cannot read property 'field' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, database, express, orm, sequelize.js

Hello I'm using the findOrCreate method to insert records, but it seems that the method does not work on include associates. Getting error if the include associate exists in DB
Using the following inputs.

> Cannot read property 'field' of undefined

First Attemp (**Successful**, relationship also created in the "through" table )

```
[
  {
    "album_type": "compilation",
    "id": "21132268",
    "name": "Album One",
    "authors": [
      {
        "name": "Node Js",
        "suffix": "Dr."
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Second Attempt **Failed** (Having a new Album but with the same author(s))

```
[
  {
    "album_type": "compilation",
    "id": "23398868",
    "name": "Album Two",
    "authors": [
      {
        "name": "Node Js",
        "suffix": "Dr."
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Error:**

> "Cannot read property 'field' of undefined",....... "TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'field' of undefined at
>   options.defaults.Object.keys.map.name ...........

**Here's the DB Functon**

```
var createAlbum = async (albums) => {
    try {
        // transaction handle
        return await models.sequelize.transaction (t => {

            // Prepare each album to be created
            return Promise.all(albums.map(album => {
                return models.Album.findOrCreate({
                    transaction: t,
                    where: {name: album.name}, // where: {id: album.id}
                    defaults: album,
                    include: ['authors']
                })
            }))
        });

    } catch (error) {
        // transaction will be rolled back if error
        logger.error(error);
        throw error;
    }
}
```

**Models**

```
//album.js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    var Album = sequelize.define('Album', {
        id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, allowNull: false },
        name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, primaryKey: true, allowNull: false },
        album_type: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },

    });

    Album.associate = (models) => {
        models.Album.belongsToMany(models.Author, {
            through: 'AlbumAuthor',
            as: 'authors',
            foreignKey: 'album_id',
            otherKey: 'author_name'
        })
    }

    return Album;
}

//author.js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    var Author = sequelize.define('Author', {
        name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, primaryKey: true, allowNull: false },
        suffix: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true }
    });

    return Author;
}

//album_author.js
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    var AlbumAuthor = sequelize.define('AlbumAuthor', {
        album_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, allowNull: false },
        author_name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, primaryKey: true, allowNull: false }
    });

    AlbumAuthor.associate = (models) => {

        models.AlbumAuthor.belongsTo(models.Album, {
            onDelete: 'CASCADE',
            foreignKey: 'album_id',
            targetKey: 'id',
        }),

        models.AlbumAuthor.belongsTo(models.Author, {
            onDelete: 'CASCADE',
            foreignKey: 'author_name',
            targetKey: 'name'
        })
    }

    return AlbumAuthor;
}
```

Comment: Hey Ben, I'm having a similar issue, do you ever solve this?

Comment: @cullanrocks unfortunately I had to abandon the framework.